# Maven Error Building MILO OPC-UA

Tags: maven, opc-ua, milo

I am trying to build Milo to run the standalone examples. From the project root I run `mvn clean install` but maven complaints about all `org.opcfoundation.*` dependencies both in `bsd-parser-core` and `bsd-parser-gson`.

Error message:

```
[INFO] 45 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Eclipse Milo Build Tools ........................... SUCCESS [  1.134 s]
[INFO] Eclipse Milo - OPC-UA (IEC 62541) .................. SUCCESS [  1.420 s]
[INFO] opc-ua-stack ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.026 s]
[INFO] stack-core ......................................... SUCCESS [ 13.145 s]
[INFO] stack-client ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.195 s]
[INFO] opc-ua-sdk ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.985 s]
[INFO] sdk-core ........................................... SUCCESS [  1.842 s]
[INFO] bsd-parser ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.240 s]
[INFO] bsd-parser-core .................................... FAILURE [  1.274 s]
[INFO] sdk-client ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] stack-server ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] sdk-server ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] milo-examples ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] server-examples .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] client-examples .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] standalone-examples ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] bsd-parser-gson .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] stack-examples ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] stack-tests ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] sdk-tests .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.517 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-16T15:16:34+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/575M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (java-compile) on project bsd-parser-core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[50,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[51,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[52,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[169,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StructuredType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[171,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StructuredType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[352,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FieldType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[374,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FieldType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[398,68] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SwitchOperand
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[419,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FieldType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericStructCodec.java:[23,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericStructCodec.java:[27,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StructuredType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.GenericStructCodec
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericEnumCodec.java:[21,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericEnumCodec.java:[25,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class EnumeratedType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.GenericEnumCodec
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericEnumCodec.java:[27,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class EnumeratedType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.GenericEnumCodec
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[22,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[23,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[24,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[25,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[78,65] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class EnumeratedType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.parser.BsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[86,67] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StructuredType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.parser.BsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericBsdParser.java:[18,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericBsdParser.java:[19,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericBsdParser.java:[24,56] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class EnumeratedType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.GenericBsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericBsdParser.java:[29,58] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StructuredType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.GenericBsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[182,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FieldType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[186,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FieldType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[259,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FieldType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[263,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FieldType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[391,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SwitchOperand
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[392,44] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable SwitchOperand
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[400,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable EQUALS
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[402,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable NOT_EQUAL
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[404,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable GREATER_THAN
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[406,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[408,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable LESS_THAN
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[410,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[43,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ObjectFactory
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.parser.BsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[45,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class TypeDictionary
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.parser.BsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[45,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class TypeDictionary
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.parser.BsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[48,67] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class EnumeratedType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.parser.BsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[50,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class EnumeratedType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.parser.BsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[50,50] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class EnumeratedType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.parser.BsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[59,67] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StructuredType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.parser.BsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[61,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StructuredType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.parser.BsdParser
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/parser/BsdParser.java:[61,50] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StructuredType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.parser.BsdParser
```

Do I need to fetch something from additional repositories?

I am using Maven 3.3.9 and Java JDK version: 1.8.0_111, from Oracle Corporation.

EDIT 1

After execute `git pull` the project built run nicely, as show below:

```
Results :

Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:verify (default) @ sdk-tests ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ sdk-tests ---
[INFO] Installing D:\PRODUTECH\Workspace\milo\opc-ua-sdk\sdk-tests\target\sdk-tests-0.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\milo\sdk-tests\0.2.2-SNAPSHOT\sdk-tests-0.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing D:\PRODUTECH\Workspace\milo\opc-ua-sdk\sdk-tests\pom.xml to C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\milo\sdk-tests\0.2.2-SNAPSHOT\sdk-tests-0.2.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Eclipse Milo Build Tools ........................... SUCCESS [  1.207 s]
[INFO] Eclipse Milo - OPC-UA (IEC 62541) .................. SUCCESS [  1.337 s]
[INFO] opc-ua-stack ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.146 s]
[INFO] stack-core ......................................... SUCCESS [ 19.878 s]
[INFO] stack-client ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.471 s]
[INFO] opc-ua-sdk ......................................... SUCCESS [  1.037 s]
[INFO] sdk-core ........................................... SUCCESS [  2.381 s]
[INFO] bsd-parser ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.227 s]
[INFO] bsd-parser-core .................................... SUCCESS [  3.927 s]
[INFO] sdk-client ......................................... SUCCESS [  8.032 s]
[INFO] stack-server ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.538 s]
[INFO] sdk-server ......................................... SUCCESS [ 13.693 s]
[INFO] milo-examples ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.203 s]
[INFO] server-examples .................................... SUCCESS [  3.474 s]
[INFO] client-examples .................................... SUCCESS [  1.059 s]
[INFO] standalone-examples ................................ SUCCESS [  0.756 s]
[INFO] bsd-parser-gson .................................... SUCCESS [  2.253 s]
[INFO] stack-examples ..................................... SUCCESS [  1.168 s]
[INFO] stack-tests ........................................ SUCCESS [01:40 min]
[INFO] sdk-tests .......................................... SUCCESS [ 20.385 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:06 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-20T15:03:53+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 88M/2061M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, when I try to build the standalone examples, running `mvn package -P standalone` from the project root, the previous error shows up again, as shown below:

```
[INFO] 45 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Eclipse Milo Build Tools ........................... SUCCESS [  1.034 s]
[INFO] Eclipse Milo - OPC-UA (IEC 62541) .................. SUCCESS [  1.414 s]
[INFO] opc-ua-stack ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.948 s]
[INFO] stack-core ......................................... SUCCESS [ 14.015 s]
[INFO] stack-client ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.972 s]
[INFO] opc-ua-sdk ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.935 s]
[INFO] sdk-core ........................................... SUCCESS [  1.679 s]
[INFO] bsd-parser ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.187 s]
[INFO] bsd-parser-core .................................... FAILURE [  1.222 s]
[INFO] sdk-client ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] stack-server ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] sdk-server ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] milo-examples ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] server-examples .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] client-examples .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] standalone-examples ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] bsd-parser-gson .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] stack-examples ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] stack-tests ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] sdk-tests .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.650 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-20T15:06:43+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/1294M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (java-compile) on project bsd-parser-core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[50,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[51,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[52,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[169,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StructuredType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[171,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StructuredType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[352,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FieldType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[374,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FieldType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[398,68] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SwitchOperand
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/AbstractCodec.java:[419,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FieldType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.AbstractCodec<StructureT,MemberT>
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericStructCodec.java:[23,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericStructCodec.java:[27,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StructuredType
[ERROR] location: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.GenericStructCodec
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericEnumCodec.java:[21,44] package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/PRODUTECH/Workspace/milo/opc-ua-stack/bsd-parser/bsd-parser-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/binaryschema/GenericEnumCodec.java:[25,19] cannot find symbol 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The org.opcfoundation.* sources are generated during the 'generate-sources' phase and placed in ../target/generated-sources. In Eclipse, you have to add this folder to the build-path.
Open the properties dialog for bsd-parser-core, open the build path folder and add the source folder.

[image: build-path dialog]

Comment: It works, thank you! Just have to point the next folder: `bsd-parser-core/target/generated-sources/jaxb2`. Otherwise Eclipse will ask you to change the package declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you fetched/updated recently? There were some issues with version numbers that broke the build recently: https://github.com/eclipse/milo/issues/230

They have been fixed on HEAD

Comment: Please check the question EDIT.

Comment: Btw, when I first asked I've only done `git clone`. Only after your answer I've tried `git pull`. I've also deleted all contents and executed the same steps with the same results.

Comment: I've imported the project in Eclipse, downloaded the `<artifactId>bsd-parser-core</artifactId><version>0.2.1</version>` jar artifact from Maven Central and added it to the build path of the project and it worked. My guess is that the source code for all `org.opcfoundation.*` is missing.

Comment: After manually adding all `org.opcfoundation.*` source code to the project it seems that there are some issues left.
`parseTypeDictionary(org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.GenericBsdParserTest)  Time elapsed: 0.811 sec  <<< FAILURE!
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://opcfoundation.org/BinarySchema/", local:"TypeDictionary"). Expected elements are <{}Documentation>,<{}TypeDictionary>


Results :

Failed tests:
  GenericBsdParserTest>BsdParserTest.parseTypeDictionary:90 » Unmarshal unexpect...`

Comment: The org.opcfoundation code is auto-generated. Running `mvn clean install` at the project root should generate. In Eclipse IDE you might have to trigger that somehow - I don't know for sure, I don't use it.

Comment: Ok seems that I am messing around too much :) Now I've cloned into a new folder, deleted all resources from .m2 repository and updated Maven to version 3.5.3, I get: `Tests run: 147, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.028 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
testInitialize(org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.BuiltinDataTypeDictionaryInitializerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.043 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: null
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.BuiltinDataTypeDictionaryInitializerTest.testInitialize(BuiltinDataTypeDictionaryInitializerTest.java:37)`

Comment: Are you sure you aren't running with Java 9? (have not verified that it's an issue myself, but have heard mixed reports)

Comment: What's the output of `mvn -v` run at the root?

Comment: Yes, running Java 8: `java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)`

And executing `mvn -v` at project root gives:
`Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T19:49:05Z)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"`

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot. It builds for me on macOS without issue, as well as on the Travis CI servers which are Linux, and the Eclipse Jenkins instance, which is also Linux. I don't have a Windows 10 VM to test with right now, if that matters.

Comment: Maven 3.5.2, Java 1.8.0_151

Comment: Try stopping by the gitter.im channel to see if anybody else has suggestions or solved any issues like this.

Comment: No problem, I will run it in a Linux VM and check, if the problem persists I will try the channel. Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Also failed running a clean Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS VM in `stack-tests`. Error follows `testClientReconnect(org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.ClientServerTest)  Time elapsed: 60.036 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaException: status=Bad_Timeout, message=request timed out after 60000ms
 at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.ClientServerTest.testClientReconnect(ClientServerTest.java:426)
Caused by: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaException: request timed out after 60000ms`

Comment: @the_grandson that's a different, spurious timing-related test failure that I haven't been able to track down. You can rebuild and hopefully it succeeds or build with `-DskipTests`.

Comment: I've compiled the whole project without problems, when compiling the standalone examples `mvn package -P standalone -DskipTests` got the same error (on `bsd-parser-core`): `package org.opcfoundation.opcua.binaryschema does not exist`. Thank you for you support I'll try the channel.

Comment: Run `mvn install` for the whole project so that the artifacts exist in your m2 cache.

Comment: I've done it previously. Finally i'm running the examples, downloaded the 'bsd-parser' jar's from Maven Central and skipped the tests. I think there's some issue with the `jaxb2-maven-plugin` because it's not generating the Java classes from the `OPCBinarySchema.xsd`.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you get it working. The only issues I know about and others have seen are when running on Java 9/10. There doesn't seem to be a functioning jaxb2 plugin for 9/10 at the moment.